# How to use paginate with relationships in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am trying to use `paginate` while selecting data from database by using relationships. I have **three** tables namely, `users`, `contacts` and `contact_messages` with **models** `User`, `Contact`, `ContactMessage` respectively.

I am trying to fetch all messages of a particular user by using the following method :

```
public function listMessage($user_id){
        $user1 = User::find($user_id);
        $messages = $user1->contact_messages;
        return View::make('message.listmessage')
        ->with('user_id', $user_id)
        ->with('messages', $messages);
    }
```

By this method I am getting all messages, but I couldn't paginate `$messages` . How can I paginate `$messages`? Can anyone help?

My models and relationships are given below :

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function contacts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Contact');
    }
    public function contact_messages()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\ContactMessage', 'App\Contact');
    }
}
```

and Contact Model is

```
class Contact extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ContactMessage');
    }
}
```

finally ContactMessage model is

```
class ContactMessage extends Model
{
    public function contact(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Contact');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$messages  = $user->contact_messages()->paginate(10);
```